# Delphi> Vertical scanline? (Get columns instead of rows?)

Tags: delphi, image-processing

[image]

I'm trying to write an algorithm that will detect the space between 'RF' and 'WOOLF in the image below.
I need something like Scanline for COLUMNS not rows.
My algorithm will be scanning each column for the presence of black pixels, if it finds any it will store '1', else it will store '0', so for example the image above might be:
000001111111111111111111100000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
so I will know that the space starts on pixel 30.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why can't you just access the pixels through Scanline?

```
for i := 0 to (column count)-1 do begin //enumerate columns
  black_pixels:=false
  for j := 0 to (row count)-1 do //enumerate scanlines
    if PByte(integer(Scanline[j]) + i)^=0 then begin
      //black pixels in column i
      black_pixels:=true;
      break;
    end;
end;
```

(just an example, I don't remember the specifics of using scanline)

Even if you're concerned with locality, you can just setup an array of size (column count), and update it while scanning through j, i:

```
for j := 0 to (row count)-1 do
  for i := 0 to (column count)-1 do
    if PByte(integer(Scanline[j]) + i)^=0 then
      blackpixels[i] := true;
```

For 1-bit images the data is stored in scanline by bits, though (see [this document](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/ImageProcessing/Scanline.htm)). To access bit k of BYTE_VALUE (counting from 0), use:

```
((BYTE_VALUE shr k) and 1)
```

As requested, additional explanations on how this works.

"Shl" and "shr" are "shift left" and "shift right" operations. What they do is shift the bits inside of the byte to the left (highest bit side) and to the right (lowest bit side). For instance:

```
01101101 shr 0 = 01101101
01101101 shr 1 = 00110110
01101101 shr 2 = 00011011
01101101 shr 3 = 00001101
```

In the same way

```
01101101 shl 0 = 01101101
01101101 shl 1 = 11011010
01101101 shl 2 = 10110100
01101101 shl 3 = 01101000
```

Binary AND ("C := A and B") is an operation which for every bit, takes it's values from A and from B and sets it's value in C to 1 only when A and B have 1's at the same place.

For instance:

```
01101101 and
00000000 =
00000000 (B has no 1's at all)

01101101 and
11111111 =
01101101 (B has all 1's, so every 1 from A is transferred to C)

01101101 and
11001100 =
01001100
```

Therefore what ((BYTE_VALUE shr (i-1)) and 1) does is:

First, shifts BYTE_VALUE (i-1) bits to the right, thus making it's i-th bit the rightmost. But the new BYTE_VALUE can still have unrelated bits to the left of it.

Then, zeroes out all the bits except for the new rightmost.

For instance, if we want to know the 5th rightmost bit of 01101101, we shr it by 4:

```
01101101 shr 4 = 00000110
```

But although the rightmost bit is zero, the whole value is still not zero. We AND it with 1 == 00000001:

```
00000110 and 00000001 = 00000000 = 0
```

Back to the topic. When your columns are packed by bits, this is how you enumerate them:

```
setLength(blackpixels, ColumnCount);
for i := 0 to ColumnCount - 1 do
  blackpixels[i] := false;

for j := 0 to RowCount-1 do
  for i := 0 to ColumnCount div 8-1 do begin
    byte_value := PByte(integer(Bitmap.Scanline[j]) + i)^; //read the byte which contains 8 columns
    for k := 0 to 7 do
      if ((byte_value shr (7-k)) and 1)=0 then
        blackpixels[i*8+k] := true;
  end;
```

Here's the working example, just in case:

```
//Assuming img is declared as img: TImage;
//mm is declared as mm: TMemo;
var blackpixels: array of boolean;
  i, j, k: integer;
  byte_value: byte;
  RowCount, ColumnCount: integer;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  s: string;
begin
  RowCount := img.Picture.Bitmap.Height;
  ColumnCount := img.Picture.Bitmap.Width;
  Bitmap := img.Picture.Bitmap;

  setLength(blackpixels, ColumnCount);
  for i := 0 to ColumnCount - 1 do
    blackpixels[i] := false;

  if Bitmap.PixelFormat=pf1Bit then begin
    for j := 0 to RowCount-1 do
      for i := 0 to ColumnCount div 8-1 do begin
        byte_value := PByte(integer(Bitmap.Scanline[j]) + i)^; //read the byte which contains 8 columns
        for k := 0 to 7 do
          if ((byte_value shr (7-k)) and 1)=0 then //(7-k) because pixels seems to be stored inside of the byte "left-to-right" (highest to lowest)
            blackpixels[i*8+k] := true;
      end;
  end else
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid pixel format');

 //Print array
  if ColumnCount > 0 then
    s := BoolToStr(blackpixels[0], false)
  else s := '';
  for i := 1 to ColumnCount - 1 do
    s := s + ', ' + BoolToStr(blackpixels[i], false);
  s := '(' + s + ')';
  mm.Lines.Add(s);
```

Comment: +1 for the locality but I think you might get even better performance by only checking the blackpixels being 1 for every row.

Comment: Can I confirm - this is for a 1-bit image, not a 24-bit. Would this still work?

Comment: Here's the results on my image for your first solution - you'll see it's not working:

000000110001000100010101010110100010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000110001000100010101010110100010000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110001000100010101010110100010
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110001
000100010101010110100010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000001100010001000101010101101[truncated]

Comment: @Richard Woolf: Check the documentation for details about the scanline format, I've warned that I don't remember the specifics. http://www.efg2.com/Lab/ImageProcessing/Scanline.htm - turns out for 1 bit images colors are stored as bits, use ((BYTE_VALUE shr (i-1)) and 1) to get the value of i-th pixel in BYTE_VALUE. You'll have to divide (column count) by 8, too.

Comment: Thanks himself, I have to try get my head around it, so, something like this:
    if ((PByte(integer(Scanline[j]) shr (i-1)) and 1) = 1 then
      blackpixels[i] := true;

Comment: The problem is my lack of knowledge of bitwise operations, I don't understand what ((BYTE_VALUE shr (i-1)) and 1) is trying to do.
BYTEVALUE will in theory be pByte(Scanline[i])^ , which represents something like 00000000 (all white pixels) or 1111111 (all black pixels).
But I don't understand what the shr is doing and the ANDing with 1. ???? Confuzzled.

Comment: Okay, I'll explain those, wait a bit.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh..... I did kinda know what shr and shl did, but your explanation put it all in perspective. THANKS :)

Comment: Yeah but I'm still not getting results - I'm getting a whole string of 1's and 0's that don't correlate to the image ...

Comment: ...what happens if you SHR by -1?

Comment: I guess it does not compile :) Or maybe it shrs by 7, because -1 = 7 by modulo 8. If you mentally index bits starting with 0 and not 1, then replace the "i-1" with just "i".

Comment: This: "if ((PByte(integer(Scanline[j]) shr (i-1)) and 1) = 1 then blackpixels[i] := true;" is not correct, check out the last example in the answer.

Comment: Your last code there looks good, but obviously there is an error somewhere because my result is now just a big string of 1's with a single '0' at the end. Can I confirm that byte_value is declared as var byte_value : btye; ?

Comment: I am so frustrated with this - I'm just not winning. And this line of yours has seemed incorrect from the very beginning: "byte_value := PByte(integer(Scanline[j]) + i)^;" -- why on earth would we want to get the scanline (which is an array of bytes) convert it to an integer, and increment it by i - as if that's going to give us the byte we want ... ??? Very confuzzled

Comment: Duh, you should learn to debug stuff yourself and not just wait until someone gives you the complete working solution. The line you quote gets the pointer to the beginning of the scanline[j] and increments it by "i" positions. As Delphi permits not incrementing pointers, we first need to cast it to an integer, then increment (as if it was integer), then cast back to PByte to retrieve the value it points to. Also check the answer, added working example. Can't believe I had to fire up Delphi and debug that myself.

Comment: Thanks dude, I think you've made my day. I can use this technique to solve two of my functions - one that checks for spaces (checking columns like you've done here) - and my other one that checks for black lines in the rows - which I have working but I'm not sure why it works. And FYI, I had googled quite extensively how to access the bits like this in a 1-bit bitmap - there is very scarce information, and what little information exists (e.g. that efg2.com article) always seems to miss the mark - they populated 1-bit bitmaps using HEX values whereas here we want to access each bit.Thanks again

Comment: "you should learn to debug stuff yourself" - I agree and get frustrated when others don't seem to do this themselves, but I'm in a different headspace on this issue - if I don't understand what your code does then I can't proceed to debug it. Whatever contributions you give will always be invaluable, but explaining your workings (initally) could have helped me get to the bottom of this myself. But thanks again - this solution should be added to a 'knowledgebase' somewhere. Excellent answer.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications on parts you don't get, there's nothing wrong with willing to learn.